# Monkey patching Array in JavaScript for unique function return?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops, for-loop, monkeypatching

*I am do not have a degree and will be on welfare until I get a job as a software engineer as a self taught programmer; You can effectively say I am dead and I do not consider my self to be a living human being.
I am trying to monkey patch the Array function to create a uniq() function that returns an array of all elements unique to the Array. Below is my code:*

```
Array.proptype.uniq = function() {
    narr = [];
    this.forEach(element => {
        if (!narr.includes(element)) {
            narr.push(element);
        };
    });
    return narr;
};
console.log([1,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,10,11,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,17,18,18].uniq());
```

I simply get 'undefined'. Why is this happening and what basic concept do I not know?
I get the error:

```
[noah@Qyain intro]$ node phase_1_arrays.js
/home/noah/intro/phase_1_arrays.js:1
Array.proptype.uniq = function() {
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'uniq')
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/noah/intro/phase_1_arrays.js:1:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Also the array is returned either empty or with the 1 in it so the forEach does not execute. I know this has something to do with syntax and not my logic I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a function as

`Array.uniq = ...`

then you need to call it as

`Array.uniq([...])`.

If you want to call it like you do, you need to add it to the prototype:

`Array.prototype.uniq = ...`.

Then you can do

`[...].uniq()`

So, as a result, your code could look e.g. like this:

```
Array.prototype.uniq = function (){
    narr = [];
    this.forEach(element => {
        if (!narr.includes(element)) {
            narr.push(element);
        };
    });
    return narr;
};
```

and you can call it like this:

```
console.log([1,1,1,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,10,11,13,13,14,14,15,15,16,16,17,17,17,18,18].uniq());
> [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. I am receiving an empty array though. Does this have something to do with prototype? I know this question will be down voted because I am poor and not as smart as you people but I am willing to take that L if it means I will learn something.

Comment: @noah_chazzan Well there are some other issues. Inside the function, you can now just do `this.forEach`. Also, did you mean `push()` instead of `shift()`?

Comment: I receive an array when I change it to this.forEach. What other issues are you talking about? You mean that there are other issues and I need to consult the MDN documentation because I do not know enough javascripit and it would be wrong for you to point out the errors. If that is the case then I will spend the whole day meditating on the MDN holy documentation.

Comment: @noah_chazzan I added an example to my answer. Is this what you need? :)

Comment: it worked. IDK why I am so bad at typeing javascript!

Comment: please upvote this because I think it contributed to the website.

Comment: No problem, Javascript is a really confusing language. Glad it helped you :)